# A question from Asymmetric random walk

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

I am studying the asymmetric random walk problem from the following notes.

https://nicfreeman1209.github.io/Website/MASx52/html/Hitting-probabilities-random-walks.html#lem:E_T_biased

I am bit struggling while understanding the proof of $E(T)<\infty$.

In the notes, a random variable $K$ is defined as
$$
K = \inf\{k \in \mathbb{N}; E_k~~ occurs\}
$$
is a geometric random variable with success parameter $p^m$ and $P(E_k)=p^m$. This means $K < \infty$ a.s. and that $E(K)=p^{-m}< \infty$.

I am confused why $E(K)=p^{-m}$? Can anyone please exaplain this step? And

If $E(T) < \infty$, then how to show $P(T<\infty)=1$?

Comment: The expectation follows from the geometric distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: $E(T) < \infty \implies P(T < \infty) = 1$ is the same as $P(T = \infty) > 0\implies E(T) = \infty.$